# Dell Latitude E6420 multiple-monitors not working

Tags: 11.10, multiple-monitors, dell, intel-graphics, nvidia-optimus

Has anybody managed to use a Dell Latitude E6420 with Ubuntu 11.10 64bit installed on it with dual monitors? I could not get it working. I have the notebook plugged into the docking station with two monitors attached (one via VGA one via DVI). The same setup works pretty well with Windows 7. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I have this working, although it's worth noting that I have the Intel integrated graphics. If I boot with the laptop docked, I get the login screen replicated on both monitors, although not at the correct resolution. Once I log in, nine times out of ten, the left-hand DVI monitor goes blank but the right-hand VGA monitor is fine and at the correct resolution.

The only way I've found of waking up the left-hand monitor is to go to Displays and temporarily disable the left-hand monitor; specifically, I disable it and then click the "restore previous settings" button. Because the Displays window is necessarily on the right-hand monitor, when dropping to a single monitor, it gets moved one virtual desktop to the right -- that took a while to discover!

Aside from this, a suspend-undock-wake sequence completely and irretrievably corrupts the display on the laptop screen.